# Opening a combo box from another object

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to know if it is possible to open a combo box and see it's elements listed from another object on the form. I do not like the 'down arrow' on the combo box and would like to create something more 'stylish' if it is possible. I am wondering if there is a routine one could write and put on another object so that upon the 'on click' event, the user will see all the elements listed within the combo box and have the opportunity to select one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use the `Dropdown` method of `Combobox` object.

**Example:**

```
Dim cmb1 As ComboBox: Set cmb1 = Me.Combo1

cmb1.SetFocus ' necessary
cmb1.Dropdown
```

**Note:** The control needs to have focus so you have to set it programmatically first.